# $\int_0^{\infty}\frac{\sin x}{(1+x)^2}\,dx$ converges absolutely

Tags: real-analysis, integration, limits

This is part of problem from baby Rudin Ch 6, exer 9:

> How to show that $$\int_0^{\infty}\frac{|\sin x|}{(1+x)^2}\,dx$$ exists (i.e., $\lim\limits_{a\to\infty}(\int_0^{a}\frac{|\sin x|}{(1+x)^2}\,dx)$ exists)? (I know that $\int_0^{\infty}\frac{\sin x}{(1+x)^2}\,dx$ exists.)

I used [integration calculator](https://www.integral-calculator.com/), and it suggested me to take note of $|x|=\frac{x^2}{|x|}$, ie, they $$\int_0^{\infty}\frac{|\sin x|}{(1+x)^2}\,dx=\int_0^{\infty}\frac{\sin x}{|\sin x|}\frac{\sin x}{(1+x)^2}\,dx,$$ but then they took $\frac{\sin x}{|\sin x|}$ out, i.e., $$\int_0^{\infty}\frac{\sin x}{|\sin x|}\frac{\sin x}{(1+x)^2}\,dx=\frac{\sin x}{|\sin x|}\int_0^{\infty}\frac{\sin x}{(1+x)^2}\,dx,$$ which seems to me illegal.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Does
$$
\int_0^{+\infty} \frac {\vert \sin x \vert } {(1+x)^2} \,\mathrm dx \leqslant \int_0^{+\infty} \frac {\mathrm dx}{(1+x )^2}
$$
show the existence?